# How to convert binary fraction to decimal

Tags: binary

I have the following binary fraction:
$$ 0.010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100 $$
I want to know what number this represents in decimal. I could go like this:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot0 + \frac{1}{4}\cdot1 + \frac{1}{8}\cdot0 + ...$$
but this doesn't sound like the good approach. What's the algorithm? I searched the web and the algorithm is only presented for binary integers.

Comment: Why is the approach any worse than the equivalent one for integers? Adding up the product of bits and powers of two works for both.

Comment: There exists a better approach for integers, I mentioned it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1866165/333066)

Comment: Second query - was your original binary fraction recurring. It looks like at the end you have potentially rounded it off.

Comment: Yes, it was rounded

Comment: The approach in your link still uses the same number of basic calculations (multiplications and additions). Can you quantify what you mean by 'better'?

Comment: So your fraction was $0.01\overline{0011}$?

Comment: @IanMiller, I can't see that, can you please rewrite the approach that answer to be looking like the one in this question so that I can see clearly that they are similar?

Comment: @IanMiller, correct

Comment: In your link you do 4 multiple and 4 add: 

$\begin{aligned}
& 2\cdot0+1=1\\ 
& 2\cdot1+1=3\\
& 2\cdot3+0=6\\
& 2\cdot6+0=12\\
\end{aligned}$

The alternate way to calculate $1100_2$ would be $8\cdot1+4\cdot1+2\cdot0+1\cdot0$

Hmm I guess that approach requires calculating the powers which is therefore worse.

Comment: @IanMiller, yes, you're right, it requires calculating powers. The alternative approach is better, but I can't seem to find the analogues one for a binary fraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse your process for binary integers. I'm using a smaller number as an example: $0.101011_2$ Start from the least significant bit and work towards.

$(0+1)\div2=0.5$

$(0.5+1)\div2=0.75$

$(0.75+0)\div2=0.375$

$(0.375+1)\div2=0.6875$

$(0.6875+0)\div2=0.34375$

$(0.34375+1)\div2=0.671875$

EDIT: How it works: $$0.671875=\frac{43}{64}=\frac{1}{64}+\frac{1}{32}+\frac{0}{16}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{0}{4}+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=(((((1/2 + 1)/2 + 0)/2 + 1)/2 + 0)/2 + 1)/2$$

An aside: As your fraction is recurring you can speed up the calculation using GP techniques but I don't think that was really what you were after.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please also explain why this algorithm works? For example, the algorithm for integers works because the number $12$ can be represented in this form $12=2⋅(2⋅(2⋅(2⋅0+1)+1)+0)+0$ and from here I can clearly see why algorithm works.

Answer (score 1):

In base $10$, $0.392 = \dfrac{392}{10^3}$. Similarly, if you work in base $2$, $0.01011_2 = \dfrac{01011_2}{2^5} = \dfrac{11}{32}$ (if you want your final answer expressed as a fraction using integers in base $10$), if you have a good algorithm for converting **integers** from base $2$ to base $10$.

ADDED after OP clarified he meant a mixed periodic fraction:

Just like in base $10$, $0.03(045)_{10} = \dfrac{03045_{10} - 03_{10}}{99900_{10}}$, in base $2$ $0.01(0011)_2 = \dfrac{010011_2 - 01_2}{111100_2}$. The proof is the same as in base $10$, it uses the sum of a geometric series. I use parentheses to show the repeating part of the periodic fraction, instead of overline (that was the notation where I grew up, and it's easier to write).

Comment: only if one removes last 4 digits 0100 then fraction  is recurring:  0.01(0011). Now it is not. One can use calculator 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125

Comment: https://www.knowledgedoor.com/2/calculators/convert_a_number_with_a_non-repeating_fractional_part.html